# Android Facebook SDK: How to access app user

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am building an app for Android. I am using the facebook sdk to register and login users.
The problem is that I want to get all my friends that uses the application. Because if I ask for all my friends that would be unnecessary load for the app.

This is what I had for now using FQL

```
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

I also heared that FQL wass deprecated in the Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works after finding out that you need to change the application in the app settings in the right top corner.